# make a string from AsyncTask not null in onCreate

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, oncreate

I have a problem  i need the token to transfer it to my SessionManagement class to compare it with the saved token , but in my onCreate it's always null ,i need a workaround to make my token not null in oncreate
please help.
here is my code

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://baymd.myterranet.com/api/auth";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "code";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_TOKEN = "access_token";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String token, none,SavedToken;
    SesionManagement session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        session=new SesionManagement(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> tokens = session.getUserDetails();
        SavedToken = tokens.get(session.KEY_NAME);
        if(token==null) {//This line 
            Log.d("TOKEN ====== ", "NULLL");
        }
        session.checkLogin(token, SavedToken);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPass);
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AttemptLogin().execute();

    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params, none);
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 200) {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);
                    token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);//The token wich is null in oncreate
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, NavDraver.class);
                    i.putExtra("cjson", c.toString());
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            session.createLoginSession(token);
            Log.d("SAVED TOKEN",SavedToken);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: try passing `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` and post your stack traces.

Comment: with the saved token in shared prefs it's all ok , but with the token wich i get from async task ,

Comment: You are passing (executing AsyncTask) the token on the click. so the token is supposed to be null before that. You can initialize the token with a temporary value unless you click on button.

Comment: yes i know it , but i need somehow to get it in oncreate, a workaround maybe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
token = c.optString(TAG_TOKEN, yourDefaultValueHere);
if(token == null){
token = ""; // or whatever you want to init here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's not the hashmap , it's the token wich i get in AsyncTask do inBackground

Comment: thank you, but i need to compare token if they are same , when user opens the app again

Comment: if your problem is with the token you get from the JSONObject, try passing the default param. See the edited answer.

Comment: sir i'm sorry i din't explain right , the token is good in the assync task , it get's it , i'm searching a way to somehow put the token from async task into my onCreate , for it to not be null

Comment: but your asynctask is executed only when you click a view, right? I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking.